# Lodash/underscore function to Initialize an array with default null values of a given length

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

Is there a function in lodash to initialize an array with default null values for a given length?

Array method currently using :

```
     var myArray = Array.apply(null, Array(myArrayLength)).map(function() { return null });
```

Lodash Function trying to use :

```
     var myArray = _.times(myArrayLength, null);
```

Required array :

```
  var myArray = [null, null, .......];
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That should do the tricks:

```
_.times(arrayLength, _.constant(null));
```

eg:

```
_.times(5, _.constant(null));
[null, null, null, null, null]
```

Comment: what about if i want to fill existent array ?

Answer (score 22):

```js
_.fill(Array(arrayLength), null)

// exemple:
_.fill(Array(5), null); // [ null, null, null, null, null ]
```

**EDIT:**

I made some performance tests: https://jsperf.com/lodash-initialize-array-fill-vs-times

- `_.fill` is faster than `_.times`
- `null` is faster than `_constant(null)`

Comment: It’s this faster than make a for loop and push x times null to my array???

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using `_.fill`

```
_.fill(Array(myArrayLength), null);`
```

It seems to be faster than `_.times`, at least it is on Chrome.

See perf comparison here: https://jsperf.com/fill-vs-times/1

Comment: Duplicate answer.

Comment: It’s this faster than write a loop and make array.push. Just curious